# How do I count all values in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column that contains numbers 1 - 5, it looks something like the following

```
Column
1
2
4
3
2
1
5
2
```

How do I count the number of times each number shows up so that my final table looks like this:

```
Number | Count
1      | 2
2      | 3
3      | 1
4      | 1
5      | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by the column you want to be unique. Then you can use the aggregate function `count()`. It will be applied to each group and do the count

```
select `column` as number, 
       count(*) as count
from your_table
group by `column`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT Column AS Number, count(*) AS 'Count'
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY Column;
```